# CUDA global memory

Tags: c++, cuda

this is my code

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

  #define n 10
  __device__ int glMem[n];

  __global__ void initVals()
  {
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    glMem[i] = 0;
 }

 __global__ void test(int *out)
{
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    out[i] = 10;
}

int main()
{
const size_t sz = size_t(n)*sizeof(int);
initVals<<<1,1>>>();
int *devMem;
cudaMalloc((void **)&devMem, sz);
test<<<1, 1>>>(devMem);
int *hoMem=new int[n];
cudaMemcpy(hoMem, devMem,sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//print
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<hoMem[i]<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

IN this code I define

```
glMem
```

to size n. If I dont know the size earlier hw can I define??
for example I need to define like this.

```
__device__ int *glMem;
```

It doesnt work. Please give some code sample..

Comment: please detail your configuration: device generation and CUDA framework version

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to allocate the memory into the device.

```
// size of data
unsigned int size_of_glMem = n * sizeof(int);
// allocate device memory for result
int* glMem = NULL;
cudaMalloc( (void**) &glMem, size_of_glMem );
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this but it doesnt work..when I call the function test it gives some random numbers.

Comment: What do you mean with random values? Your code works as excepted. It prints number '10' ten times.

Comment: Yes my code works fine but when I define the array like __device__ int *glMem; and allocate the memory it doesnt work. gives wrong results..

Comment: Ops, you can not allocate device memory dynamically. You need to define your device pointer int *glMem and allocate the memory for it in the CPU. Is that what's happening ?